# Open different pages, with different Users

Tags: java, android, authentication

I am trying to make an android app. But I got a problem. Every time I log in I want to login like manager or user. I got 1 table in my database for all users. But I want it to be so when I login with the user called "manager" he will see a different screen from all the other users in the table.

```
           ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {

                    if (username == "manager") {

                        Intent takeUserHome = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ManagerHomePage.class);
                        startActivity(takeUserHome);

                    } else {
                        Intent takeUserHome = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserHomePage.class);
                        startActivity(takeUserHome);

                    }
```

This is mine current code, but when I login with manager I still get to UserHomePage instead of the ManagerHomePage

Comment: Compare strings by `equals()`, not `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are comparing the string references instead on their values. using the == operator as you do in the line

```
username == "manager"
```

This compares the references, not the actual string content. what you probably want is :

```
username.equals("manager")
```

For a more in depth explenation see: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).